# Converting parquet on S3 to string

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read a parquet file without knowing the structure stored in golang from an S3 bucket.

Using the Body from the GetObjectOutput struct, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#GetObjectOutput, I pass it to ioutil and convert it to a string but it when I print the string it reads all out of place as if I opened the parquet file with a text editor.

```
res, _ := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput {
                Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
                Key: obj.Key,           
            })
b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
fmt.Printf("%v", string(b))
```

Comment: The printed bytes of a text file will look similar to the view of the same file in a text editor.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you using a library that understands how to read Parquet files?

Comment: @MuffinTop The problem is that my manager wants me to read a parquet file from s3 without knowing the struct and transform the data to whatever transformation a user would want and so I was trying to convert it into a string to see if I was properly reading the data.

Comment: The application should handle the error returned from ioutil.ReadAll. Otherwise, the application correctly reads the data from the object.  What have you tried so far to parse and transform the parquet data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Rotenstein advice to use a parquet reader was spot on.

I was able to use https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go to parse the parquet file.

https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go-source, can be used to retrieve a parquet file from s3 as well.